# How to read nodejs documentation regarding callback parameters (node v8.x)

Tags: node.js

I am trying to understand the node.js documentation specifically for the https.get() method. https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback

What is unclear to me is the callback. The example in the document indicates the callback can take a res (response) object as its parameter but I am unsure if this is the only parameter it can take or more importantly where I can find the definition of the res object so I can know what properties and methods I can access on this object.

Is there a straightforward way to identify this?

I have read this thread: [Trying to understand nodejs documentation. How to discover callback parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37376972/trying-to-understand-nodejs-documentation-how-to-discover-callback-parameters) and the answers seem to suggest that if there is a non-error argument that a callback can take it will be documented, but I am assuming that answer is outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run into the same issue with many Node/NPM packages. Documentation sometimes does not describe the parameters well.

So, welcome to JavaScript in 2018! It's gotten a lot better, though, to be honest.

My go-to method is to try the methods and dump the information myself.

Try a `console.dir(res)` in your callback:

```
https.get('https://encrypted.google.com/', (res) => {
  console.dir(res);
});
```

Alternatively, you can set a breakpoint in the callback and inspect it yourself. You can then probe the `arguments` [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)* to see what else, if anything, was passed as an argument, or do another console dump:

```
https.get('https://encrypted.google.com/', function (res) {
  console.dir("args:", arguments);
  console.dir("res:", res);
});
```

EDIT: Wait, apparently the `arguments` variable is **not** available to arrow functions, fixed the second example.

*From MDN:

> The arguments object is not an Array. It is similar to an Array, but
>   does not have any Array properties except length.

Answer (score 0):

From your link https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback, you can see that it works like the http version :

> Like http.get() but for HTTPS.

With `http.get()` clickable.

On that page (https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback), we can see this :

> The callback is invoked with a single argument that is an instance of http.IncomingMessage

With `http.IncomingMessage` clickable, linking this page :

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage

I agree the Node documentation is not very clear about the callbacks in general, and that is a shame. You can still use IDEs with good intellisense (and JSDoc to identify the type  of the function parameters), like VSCode.

Or you can use a debugger, always works :)

**Edit:** If you want to see all the parameters sent to a function, you can use the spread syntax like this :

```
function foo(...params) {
    // Here params is an array containing all the parameters that were sent to the function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the absolute truth, you can look at the [implementation](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/http.js). Though that's fairly time consuming.

If you find that the documentation is wrong, or in this case could be improved by adding a sentence about the callback parameter to `https.get()`, please open an issue, or, better yet, a pull request. This is where the change needs to be made: 
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/67790962daccb5ff19c977119d7231cbe175c206/doc/api/https.md